# Try to make a Crystal Report that takes a parameter

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, report

I'm trying to make a Crystal Report using Visual Basics in Visual Studio 2013. I need to report to first select an ID number from the database(using a dropdown list) and then pull up the record with that id.

I'm having problems with the first step. I can't get it to produce a dropdown list where it can select the variable and then pull up the report.

I've tried create a drop down list outside the report and send that as a parameter to pull up the information, but that has not been successful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want help, please provide what you have tried; code, snippets etc. If you can't provide this information it's really hard for us to help you.

Comment: I'm looking for a place to start. Like code that shows how to create a drop down list that can be used in Crystal Reports for the task I specified in the description.

Comment: You said, "first select an ID number from the database(using a dropdown list)" - have you successfully filled this, if not I would get this first; and you have indicated that you can't get it to produce a dropdown list... So get this first, then explain what you have tried as far as sending this value to the report.

Comment: I can give you the code for that, but I meant that I created a drop down list on the web form that gets the id number and tries to enter it into crystal reports. but report comes up with an error of missing parameter.

Comment: I edited to code in. So you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that on Crystal. Go ahead and create a parameter and under `List of Values` select dynamic. Then choose the database field you want that parameter to pull records under `Value`. You can also setup some properties for that parameter under settings. See picture below as example. When you are done click on Ok and on your record selection formula make the `ID number` = to the parameter, so when you call the report it will prompt on that parameter, that will be a drop down with all the ID numbers you have on that table.

[image]

Comment: You're awesome!! Thanks!! I also needed to add another stored procedure to get all the ID Numbers, since the stored procedure already included, only output one request number. Just An FYI for anyone else who has this problem.

Comment: I am glad I could helped you. You are more than welcome.

Comment: Got a problem, it only lets me select the value with the report wizard, when I test it through internet explorer, it just loads the number loaded when I last tested it in the report wizard. If I try to change it, and tells me to log into the database, but it never logs in so I can change it.

Comment: when you preview the report in VS, please make sure that you have unchecked Save data in the report, you can find that below the report name tab on Main Report Preview

Comment: Then it tells me I'm  missing parameter values

Comment: if you run the report by itself, does it prompt on that parameter as it should be?

Comment: No. It just comes up with the "Missing Parameter Values" error. Nothing else. Could it be because I have subreports?

Comment: to be frank, I don't know to much about .net. When I have to call a report using .net, I create a web form, add crystal report viewer and crystal report source, config them and that's it. crystal reports runtime does the rest.

Comment: It works the same way with .Net. I was able to create multiple ones that work fine, but this one was too complex, it may not be possible. Thanks for the help though, you got me a good ways in.